# Bug or feature? Unable to do two consecutive steps of multiprocessing in a python script

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, joblib

I have two consecutive functions that process large lists.

I call one after another, using **`joblib`**'s `Parallel, delayed`, in an attempt to increase a processing speed for both functions individually.

However, I am seeing an output from `function_1` also as soon as `Parallel` calls `function_2` and I don't understand why. **In a nutshell, this leads to a `function_2` not being called.**

**The main code:**

```
from mycode import function_2
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import gc

if __name__ == '__main__':  
   list = list_1
   print ">>> First call"
   Parallel(n_jobs = -1)(delayed(function_1) 
                                         (item) for item in list)
   gc.collect()
   do_other_stuff()
   list = list_2
   print ">>> Second call"
   Parallel(n_jobs=-1, backend='threading')(delayed(function_2)
                                         (item) for item in list)
```

**Threaded functions:**

```
def function_1(): # Gets called first
    print "this comes from function 1"
    pass

def function_2(): # Gets called second
    print "this comes from function 2"
    pass
```

**Output**:

```
>>> First call
this comes from function 1
this comes from function 1
this comes from function 1
this comes from function 1
>>> Second call
this comes from function 1
this comes from function 1
this comes from function 1
this comes from function 1
```

**My hypothesis** is that there are some parts of `function_1` stored in a memory, which is retained after calling it ( possibly due to a `joblib` memory mapping / sharing feature? ).

This is why I `gc.collect()` between the calls. Since this doesn't help, I think about [reloading modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/437589/6060083) between calls ( `joblib, Parallel, delayed` ), which seems ugly.

**Did anyone experience similar behavior (on windows)?**

**Is there some fix?**

**Do I need to un/reload `joblib` or `mycode` modules here, between `Parallel` steps and if so, why?**

Comment: How long is `list_1`/`list_2`? (also, side-note: Never name-shadow the `list` constructor, it will bite you eventually). Need to know how many outputs you were expecting in the first place. For the record, your explanation is almost certainly wrong unless `joblib` is the world's most amateur library ever.

Comment: List_1 is about 1.000, list_2 is ~10.000. In the real code, the list constructors are named different. Also, instead of the pass, there is output of both functions stored to disc as CSV (not returned)

Comment: Are you sure you never get output from the second function? Looks like in the process of minimizing your example, you forgot the complete and verifiable parts of a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.

My code looked like:

```
A = Parallel(n_jobs=1)(delayed(self.function_1)( df_1, item ) for item in list_of_items)

B = Parallel(n_jobs=1)(delayed(self.function_2)( df_2, item ) for item in list_of_items)
```

where "list_of_items" variable had 2 items.

But the output was...

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   2 out of   2 | elapsed:   32.2s finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   0 out of   0 | elapsed:    0.0s finished
```

The reason why the second Parallel process didn't run (at least in my case) was because my "list_of_items" was a generator instead of a list!

I hope this solves your problem too.. :)

Answer (score 3):

### Short version:

**Q1**: Did anyone experience similar behavior (on windows)?
**A1:** No.

**Q2**: Is there some fix?
**A2**: No, ref. A1.

**Q3**: Do I need to un/reload `joblib` or `mycode` modules here ...?
**A3**: No, ref. A1.

**Q4**: if so ( Q3 ), why?
**A4**: N/A, ref. A3.

---

### Let'drive our efforts based on a common MCVE formulation:

A slightly modified structure of the experiment may look like this:

```
#ass;                         import function_2
from sklearn.externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
#ass;                         import gc
pass;                         import itertools

def function_1( aParam = "" ):                                          # Gets called first
    try:
         print "this comes from a call: function_1( aParam == {0:})".format( aParam )

    except:
         pass # die in silence

    finally:
         return aParam

def function_2( aParam = "" ):                                          # Gets called second
    try:
         print "this comes from a call: function_2( aParam == {0:})".format( aParam )

    except:
         pass # die in silence

    finally:
         return aParam

if __name__ == '__main__':
   print "-------------------------------------------------------------- vvv main.START()"
   #ist = list_1
   aList = [ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, ]
   print "-------------------------------------------------------------- >>> First call"
   A = Parallel(                                               n_jobs = -1
                 )( delayed( function_1 ) ( item ) for item in aList
                    )
   print "-------------------------------------------------------------- vvv main was ret'd: {0:}".format( repr( A ) )
   #c.collect()
   #o_other_stuff()
   #ist = list_2
   aList = [ 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, ]
   print "-------------------------------------------------------------- >>> Second call"
   B = Parallel(                                               n_jobs  = -1,
                                                               backend = 'threading'
                 )( delayed( function_2 ) ( item ) for item in aList
                    )
   print "-------------------------------------------------------------- vvv main was ret'd: {0:}".format( repr( B ) )
```

---

### Result:

```
C:\Python27.anaconda>python TEST_SO_Parallel.py
-------------------------------------------------------------- vvv main.START()
-------------------------------------------------------------- >>> First call
this comes from a call: function_1( aParam == 11)
this comes from a call: function_1( aParam == 12)
this comes from a call: function_1( aParam == 13)
this comes from a call: function_1( aParam == 14)
this comes from a call: function_1( aParam == 15)
-------------------------------------------------------------- vvv main was ret'd: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
-------------------------------------------------------------- >>> Second call
this comes from a call: function_2( aParam == 21)
this comes from a call: function_2( aParam == 22)
this comes from a call: function_2( aParam == 23)
 this comes from a call: function_2( aParam == 25)this comes from a call: function_2( aParam == 24)

-------------------------------------------------------------- vvv main was ret'd: [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
```

---

### Assessment:

As observed, a [win] py2.7 has processed the code without any above reported obstacles.

The **`joblib`**-documented processing was correct as per specification.

The above reported behaviour was not replicated, the less could be mapped to any form of a `joblib`-participation on the cause-effect chain.